# Variational autoencoder : InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [100,5] vs. [100]

Tags: python, keras, lstm, autoencoder

I try to run variational autoencoder with LSTM. So I replace the `dense` layer with `LSTM` layer. But it doesn't work. This the example:

```
# generate data
data = generate_example(length = 560,seed=253)
normal_data = data[1:400,:]
fault_data = data[400:,:]
timesteps = 5

# data prepare
# define the normalize function
# normalize function
def normalize(normal, fault):
    normal_mean = normal.mean(axis = 0)
    normal_std = normal.std(axis = 0)
    # normalize
    fault_normalize = np.array(fault).reshape(fault.shape)
    for i in np.linspace(0,fault.shape[1]-1):
        i = int(i)
        fault_normalize[:,i] = (fault[:,i] - normal_mean[i])/normal_std[i]
    return(fault_normalize)
# define the lag function
# lag function
def lag(data, timesteps = 10):
    # define the shape of return data
    data_row = data.shape[0]
    data_col = data.shape[1]
    data_len = data_row - timesteps

    data_lag = np.repeat(0,data_len*timesteps*data_col).reshape(data_len,timesteps,data_col).astype("float")
    for i in np.arange(0,data_len):
        data_lag[i,:,:] = data[i:(i+timesteps),:]
    return(data_lag)

normal_scale = normalize(normal = normal_data, fault = normal_data)
normal_scale = lag(data=normal_scale, timesteps = timesteps)
```

This is the variational autoencoder

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda, LSTM, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras import metrics
from keras.datasets import mnist

batch_size = 100
original_dim = 3
latent_dim = 2
intermediate_dim = 5
epochs = 100
epsilon_std = 1.0


x = Input(shape=(timesteps,original_dim))
h = LSTM(intermediate_dim,return_sequences=False)(x)
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim)(h)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim)(h)


def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(z_mean)[0], latent_dim), mean=0.,
                              stddev=epsilon_std)
    return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_var / 2) * epsilon

# note that "output_shape" isn't necessary with the TensorFlow backend
z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean, z_log_var])

# we instantiate these layers separately so as to reuse them later
decoded_repeat = RepeatVector(timesteps)
decoder_h = LSTM(intermediate_dim, activation='tanh',return_sequences=True)
decoder_mean = TimeDistributed(Dense(original_dim, activation='sigmoid'))

h_repeat = decoded_repeat(z)
h_decoded = decoder_h(h_repeat)
x_decoded_mean = decoder_mean(h_decoded)

# instantiate VAE model
vae = Model(x, x_decoded_mean)

# Compute VAE loss
xent_loss = original_dim * metrics.binary_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_mean)
kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
vae_loss = K.mean(xent_loss + kl_loss)

vae.add_loss(vae_loss)
vae.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss=None)
vae.summary()


x_train = normal_scale
x_test = normal_scale

vae.fit(x_train,
        shuffle=True,
        epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=batch_size)

# build a model to project inputs on the latent space
encoder = Model(x, z_mean)
```

But I got the error `InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [100,5] vs. [100]`, I didn't think there is a incompatible shapes. This is structure of variational autoencoder

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_76 (InputLayer)            (None, 5, 3)          0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_42 (LSTM)                   (None, 5)             180         input_76[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_317 (Dense)                (None, 2)             12          lstm_42[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_318 (Dense)                (None, 2)             12          lstm_42[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_72 (Lambda)               (None, 2)             0           dense_317[0][0]                  
                                                                   dense_318[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_20 (RepeatVector)  (None, 5, 2)          0           lambda_72[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_43 (LSTM)                   (None, 5, 5)          160         repeat_vector_20[0][0]           
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_18 (TimeDistrib (None, 5, 3)          18          lstm_43[0][0]                    
====================================================================================================
Total params: 382
Trainable params: 382
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs in the computation of the loss function:

```
vae_loss = K.mean(xent_loss + kl_loss)
```

Here, `xent_loss` is a tensor with shape `(100, 5)`, whereas `kl_loss` has shape `(100,)`. Expanding the dimension of `kl_loss` will enable broadcasting (I pressume that's what you intended):

```
vae_loss = K.mean(xent_loss + kl_loss[:, None])
```